# how to create fields automatically mongo db

Tags: python, mongodb, nltk, pubmed

Iam trying to make an automated analysis of pubmed data , I got articles's titles , I cleaned them from stop words(considered as noise  like: and,of,is...), I want to insert each word resulted in a field in mongodb
and I am  blocked on how to do that consedering that from each title I will get different number of words , how to dynamicall create fields fo each data resulted from a title , anyy suggestions I google it but didn't find any idea about it!!

Comment: Perhaps use an array instead of discrete fields?

Comment: @Joe could you be more specific , you mean to store an array of obtained words in one field named title for example.

Comment: Exactly, then you can query the title for any single word, or use `$all` to query for multiple words.  Depend on what you are trying to do, maybe a text index would be the way to go?

Comment: @Joe what I want to do exactly is that , after insterting this data , I want to visualise it with power Bi, for example how many times each word in a title is present in onther titles of other articles. In your point of vue what will do the stuff array or text index , I am new to mongo db